# Ошибка в константном указателе на константу

Tags: указатели, const, c++

Здравствуйте. Мой вопрос возможно покажется глупым но не получается найти на него ответ. Имеется следующий код:

```
const int  ic = i;
const  int *  сpic = &ic;
```

в ответ на этот код я получаю ошибку:

> error: stray ‘\321’ in program

не очень понимаю, о чем мне говрит компилятор. Не могли бы вы объяснить, в чем тут дело? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Такое чувство, что у вас некоторые символы набраны не в английской раскладке. Попробуйте перенабрать строку, убедившись, что выбрана английская раскладка и выключен PuntoSwitcher и подобные ему приложения.

Comment: А показать весь код или хотя бы полный кусок к которому относится ваша строка не как?      
Так как из вашей строки не понятно чем является 'ic'.        
Я сделал 'ic' переменной int и у меня ваша строка скомпилировалась без единой ошибки.        
ADD:        
Ну я даже и не знаю, снова не понятная переменная 'i' но я её у себя сделал int и снова все скомпилировалось.       
ADD:    
Отдал гуглу эту ошибку и там пишут что эта ошибка из за того что в коде есть русские буквы. Попробуйте эти строки не копировать и вставлять, а в ручную набрать на английском.

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy пожалуйста

Comment: спасибо всем отписавшимся - помогло))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас  идентификатор сpic  сочетает в себе кириллические и латинские символы. Можете убедиться в этом [здесь](http://ideone.com/Ml1qzn). Видимо, ваш компилятор (а может и стандарт C++, точно не  знаю) предпочитает латиницу.  Вероятно, виной тому Punto Switcher. Во избежание таких случаев рекомендую занести в исключения Switcher'а вашу IDE, чтобы он не переключал автоматически то, что вы печатаете

Comment: PS мне напутал много кода, хотя бывает полезен в наборе длинных языковых конструкций.

Comment: Моя практика показала, что PS не место на компьютере у программиста. Капслок на переключение клавиатуры и вперед!

Comment: @KoVadim ошибаетесь - нужно всего лишь занести в исключения редакторы кода

Comment: По-моему, PS - штука полезная даже на компе у разработчика, но нужно отключить автопереключение. Если опечатался - Shift+Home, Shift+Break.